# How can I batch convert a directory of subfolders from FLAC to ALAC?

Tags: ffmpeg, terminal.app, applescript, automator, flac

Right now I'm converting each folder in Terminal manually using the following command,

```
for i in *.flac; do echo $i; ffmpeg -i "$i" -y -v 0 -vcodec copy -acodec alac  "${i%.flac}".m4a && rm -f "$i"; done
```

Of course this only affects the single folder I've accessed in Terminal and none of the subfolders. So, if I execute on Artist A, no flac is found. I have to execute on Album 1, then Album 2, etc. I have thousands of folders that need to go through this process and don't really know what the elements in the command mean so I'm unable to decipher and augment it.

There are two methods I'm considering to batch process my directory and subfolders.

1 - Execute command for directory and all subfolders. This would probably be the simplest method. Once I get all my files migrated over, I can execute the command to convert tens of thousands of files at once.

2 - Automatically convert any .flac files added to a directory. This method would a more 'set it and forget it' approach. If I ever add more files to the directory / subfolders they will always be converted.

Directory Structure:
Music
. Artist A
.. Album 1
... Track 1.flac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find . -type f -name '*.flac' -print -exec sh -c 'i="{}"; ffmpeg -i "$i" -y -v 0 -vcodec copy -acodec alac  "${i%.flac}".m4a && rm -f "$i"' \;
```

Comment: This seems to be working. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

`Forfiles /s` can do what you want. It can check files in a folder and recurse into subfolders.

The command you would want to use would be something like this (note, I can't test it so bear with me)

```
forfiles /s /m *.flac "cmd /c echo @path; ffmpeg -i ""@path"" -y -v 0 -vcodec copy -acodec alac  ""${@path.flac}"".m4a && rm -f ""@path"""
```